# GTA V Online and resume

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

I'm having a lot of problems with GTA V on XBox One and its sleep/resume mode.  The biggest one is that if I put the XBox to sleep while GTA is running, I can't connect to GTA online when resuming.  The only way I can get back in is to quit and restart GTA, which is pretty infuriating.

Does anyone else know why this is happening and how to get around it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround that's less obnoxious than quitting and reloading the game.  If you get a screen asking who you are when you resume the game, then select sign out.  Then double tap the xbox button to sign back in immediately.

If you don't get that screen, then double tap the xbox button and sign out that way.  This seems to resolve the problem.  It's not ideal but it's quicker than quitting and resuming the game.

You do need to watch out that you don't trigger a new game in the process though otherwise you'll have to replay the North Yanktown mission before you can sort it out.